# How to output MySQL data tables in CSV format?

Tags: mysql, cron, backup

I need to know how can I export 10 data tables from one database into a csv format with cron job daily?

I know this script:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE NAME
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/BACKUP.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But how can I in the same line add the another 9 tables?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `mysqldump` with the `--tab` option. It runs those `INTO OUTFILE` statements for you, dumping each table into a separate file.

You don't want all the tables in one file, because it would make it very awkward to import later.

Always be thinking about how you will restore a backup. I tell people, "you don't need a backup strategy, you need a *restore* strategy." Backing up is just a necessary step to restoring.